# Using Xamarin ImageSource.FromUri("https://my image url") how do you tell if you have retrieved an image

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, imagesource

I'm using an `ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri("https://my image uri")` and it works great.

But how do I tell if I've retrieved an image successfully?

When I supply a URI that doesn't exist I don't get any error and the FromUri() returns a UriImageSource but no image and no exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

**Take a look at the answer [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/179758/#Comment_179758)** I tried on Android and it works fine.

> **Quote**
>
> 1 - Have a look at [FFImageLoading Plugin](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/Xamarin.Forms-API), It provides all you need and more
>
> 2- Specifically the `ErrorPlaceholder` property is what you are looking for.
>   **Here you can provide an image which is shown when an error occurs!**

Comment: Thanks. I installed the plugin and got it working. Using the error event handler to load a default image.i could not get the databinding to work on the ffimageloading:CachedImage element in my xaml form. So on my event I create an ImageSource.fromUri() and this works.